# Github action, how to stay at the same branch for all other repositories involved

Tags: github, action

I have 3 github repositories A, B, C and for each repo, I have a "main" and a "develop" branch.
I do not know how to solve the following:

When I push a modification to the "develop" branch in repo B which is referred to by something in repo A and B in itself refers to repo C, I would like to run the manual workflow action for the "develop" branch in A which should use the code in the "develop" branch in B and that should use the "develop" branch in C.

The typical pre-condition is that for repo A, main and develop are in synch, the same for repo C.

To accomplish what I want, I am now forced to make a change to repo A to refer in the source to the develop tag when checking out B.

Is that possible and I'm just not familiar enough with GitHub?
This is what a part of my manual workflow yml for develop in repo A looks like:

```
jobs:
  terraform:
    name: 'Terraform'
    environment: Playground
    env:
      ARM_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_ID }}
      ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET }}
      ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_TENANT_ID }}
      ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:

    # Checkout client files to root folder
    - name: Checkout Client
      uses: actions/checkout@v3    
      with:
        ref: develop
```

One of the modules in repo A refers to the next repository B this way:

```
module "dbservers" {
  source = "git@github.com:mine/REB3Modules//databases"
```

and because I don't know any different, I'm now forced to change it to:

```
module "dbservers" {
  source = "git@github.com:mine/REB3Modules//databases?ref=develop"
```

which I think shouldn't be necessary.

Thanks for looking at this!